# The MERGE statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint - Entity framework

Tags: sql, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have the following code updating the place table with entity framework. Place table has Check constraint on column SequenceNumber. `([SequenceNumber]>=(1))`

I am trying to update the table with entity framework but when i try to update it gives me error:

> SqlException: The MERGE statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint "CK_Places_SequenceNumber". The conflict occurred in database "XXX", table "dbo.Places", column 'SequenceNumber'.

Below is the code. Just to try I even commented SequenceNumber assignment to avoid the update but i think it depends on the underlying state of entity as well.

```
       var places = placeDtos.Select(x => new Place
        {
            PlaceId = x.PlaceId,
            Name = x.Name,
            SequenceNumber = x.SequenceNumber,
            PlaceAreaId = areaId,
            PlaceInterestPlaces = x.PlaceInterests?.Select(d => new PlaceInterestPlace
            {
                PlaceId = x.PlaceId,
                PlaceInterestId = d.PlaceInterestId
            })?.ToList()
        })?.ToList();

        _dbContext.Places.UpdateRange(desks);
        await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Can someone help in making me understand whats the problem here? Thanks.

Comment: (1) How is `SequenceNumber` defined/configured in the entity model? (2) What are the values of `SequenceNumber` in `placeDtos` elements? Is there value < 1?

Comment: Its setup as int in entity and I have debugged the code the sequence number is greater then 1.

Comment: As `int` is ok, but the question was more about if it is configured as [generated value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/generated-properties?tabs=data-annotations), in which case EF Core won't update it and won't pass it to `insert`, thus violating the constraint.

Comment: This error may be caused by the MERGE statement trying to insert a record that does not have a corresponding record in the parent table. You need to make sure that the parent table is also updated from the source database before updating the child table. Can you provide more details?